# What is the syntax for passing in an argument for a "for each" loop in Array.prototype?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

If I have code like this:

```
QB_list.x.forEach(pushElementsQB)

function pushElementsQB(element, index, array)
{
    rows.push([element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index], null, null, null, null]);
}
```

Is there a way to specify the rows variable in my callback? I am new to javascript and looking at the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) isn't working for me this time :/

Comment: yes, you can specify _rows_ moving it to parameters, and predefine it with _bind_ function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grundy has mentioned, one way of doing it is setting with bind the value of this inside the function:

```
QB_list.x.forEach(pushElementsQB.bind(rows))

function pushElementsQB(element, index, array) // here this will be rows
{
    this.push([element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index], null, null, null, null]);
}
```

Which is the same as setting the second argument of forEach:

```
QB_list.x.forEach(pushElementsQB, rows)
```

Another way would also be to just add rows as an extra parameter:

```
QB_list.x.forEach(pushElementsQB.bind(QB_list.x.forEach.args,rows))
```

And then use:

```
function pushElementsQB(rows, element, index, array) // be careful, rows is the first parameter now
{
    rows.push([element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index], null, null, null, null]);
}
```

Comment: you also can add sample where rows binded as parameter

Comment: also instead _bind_ in this case possibly used second argument for _forEach_

Comment: @Grundy yeah there are really a lot of ways. Added some, thanks

Comment: This one ended up being what I needed, but the other responses were good too. I couldn't use map as easily for my particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `map`?

```
var rows = QB_list.x.map(pushElementsQB);

function pushElementsQB(element, index, array)
{
    return [element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index], null, null, null, null];
}
```

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is essentially a `forEach` which returns an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, @Mathletics's answer of `Map` would be best, but to answer the question, and extend on @juvian and @Grundy's response. You can bind the context (the `this` keyword) by using Bind. However, this is danegrous, as you make that function take that context, and those arguments *forever*, and in all other usages until unbound.

You can do this in a simpler, safer, and later more expectant way as follows.

The second parameter of Array.forEach is `thisArg`. Give this rows, and it accomplishes the same without the use of bind.

```
var rows = []; // Declare rows variable
QB_list.x.forEach(pushElementsQB, rows) // Pass it in for the callbacks context

function pushElementsQB(element, index, array) {
     this.push([element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index],  null, null, null, null]);
}
```

If you really want to impose the variable into the parameters, you can do this:

```
var rows = []; // Declare rows variable
QB_list.x.forEach(function() { 
    pushElementsQB.apply(
        QB_list.x, // Set the function to be called with list as context (`this`)
        arguments.concat([rows]) // Grab the arguments to this function, append rows, set the function to be called with that appended list
    ) 
})

function pushElementsQB(element, index, array, rows) {
    // Rows is appended to the end of the arguments list, so, maps to 'rows' argument here
    rows.push([element, QB_list.y[index], "QB: " + QB_list.text[index],  null, null, null, null]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map`, as suggested by Mathletics is a good choice. Another good reason for using it is that you can pass in an initial argument that acts as `this` in the callback. For example, if `rows` has already been declared and you want to push more data to it you can do something like the following:

```
var data = { x: [1, 2, 3, 4] };
var rows = [2];

// pass in `rows` as the initial argument
data.x.map(pushElementsQB, rows);

function pushElementsQB(el) {

  // `this` is `rows`, and `map` appends the elements
  // from data.x to it.
  return this.push(el);
}

console.log(rows); // [2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Pretty neat.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/jkeLfqpa/)

Comment: Also it's weird to use `map` if you're not doing anything with the resulting array, IMO.